# API Connect >The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect, ibm-api-management

I'm new using IBM API CONNECT, My goal is to use API CONNECT as a proxy server to provide security to my my existing REST Apis, I followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/apiconnect?topic=apiconnect-tut_import_openapi_rest_bm&locale=en-us)  but I receive the below error:

```html
<errorResponse>
  <httpCode>404</httpCode>
  <httpMessage>Not Found</httpMessage>
  <moreInformation>The requested URL was not found on this server</moreInformation>
</errorResponse>
```

Someone  know the possible cause of the error?
Thanks for you help!

Comment: This is the error: <errorResponse>
<httpCode>404</httpCode>
<httpMessage>Not Found</httpMessage>
<moreInformation>The requested URL was not found on this server</moreInformation>
</errorResponse>

Comment: You have to provide more info to let us reproduce your issue - at what request do you get this error? What steps have you completed from that tutorial?

Comment: It's likely there's a problem with your API definition, so the gateway doesn't understand that it needs to respond to the API call. Posting your API doc (swagger) would help.

Comment: I already completed "Test with the API Manager test tool" step, thank you in advice